# When installed indico, i got error on index.py

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

Im trying install indico while follow [installation guide](http://indico-software.org/wiki/Admin/Installation0.98) but there is some problem and i can't fix it.

index.py return this message on browser

```
MOD_PYTHON ERROR

ProcessId:      18206
Interpreter:    '127.0.1.1'

ServerName:     '127.0.1.1'
DocumentRoot:   '/var/www'

URI:            '/indico/index.py'
Location:       None
Directory:      '/opt/indico/htdocs/'
Filename:       '/opt/indico/htdocs/index.py'
PathInfo:       None

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'mod_python.publisher'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
    result = object(arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 213, in handler
    published = publish_object(req, object)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 425, in publish_object
    return publish_object(req,util.apply_fs_data(object, req.form, req=req))

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/util.py", line 554, in apply_fs_data
    return object(**args)

  File "/opt/indico/htdocs/index.py", line 23, in index
    return welcome.RHWelcome( req ).process( params )

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/rh/base.py", line 707, in process
    res = self._processUnexpectedError( e )

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/rh/base.py", line 382, in _processUnexpectedError
    return p.display()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/pages/base.py", line 189, in display
    return "%s%s%s"%( self._getHTMLHeader(), \

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/pages/base.py", line 169, in _getHTMLHeader
    "assets": self._asset_env

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/wcomponents.py", line 195, in getHTML
    tempHTML = templateEngine.render(self.tplFile, vars, self)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/common/TemplateExec.py", line 128, in render
    return template.render(**params)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Mako-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/mako/template.py", line 443, in render
    return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Mako-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 803, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Mako-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 835, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Mako-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 860, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/indico/tmp/mako_modules/HTMLHeader.tpl.py", line 44, in render_body
    __M_writer(str(self_._rh.csrf_token))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/rh/base.py", line 278, in csrf_token
    return self._getSession().csrf_token

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/rh/base.py", line 268, in _getSession
    self._setSession()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/rh/base.py", line 261, in _setSession
    self._websession = session.getSessionForReq(self._req)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/session/__init__.py", line 28, in getSessionForReq
    return sm.get_session(req)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/session/base.py", line 637, in get_session
    rw = RequestWrapper.getWrapper( request )

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/session/base.py", line 730, in getWrapper
    w = RequestWrapper( req )

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/MaKaC/webinterface/session/base.py", line 709, in __init__
    self.environ = {"REMOTE_ADDR": _get_remote_ip(request)}

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/indico-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/indico/util/network.py", line 31, in _get_remote_ip
    hostIP = str(req.get_remote_ip())

AttributeError: 'mp_request' object has no attribute 'get_remote_ip'


MODULE CACHE DETAILS

Accessed:       Fri Jun 20 11:54:56 2014
Generation:     1

_mp_f82f1cbab6d44e96c95ffaf5362fd5ea {
  FileName:     '/opt/indico/htdocs/index.py'
  Instance:     1
  Generation:   1
  Modified:     Fri Jun 20 10:38:13 2014
  Imported:     Fri Jun 20 10:57:15 2014
}
```

I don't understand what is the problem..

python -V > Python 2.7.3

apache2 -v > Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

```
libapache2-mod > 3.3-4+deb7u1
```

Comment: Please don't use ``mod-python``. The accepted pseudo-standard is ``mod_wsgi`` or reverse proxy.

Comment: @JamesMills thanks. I installed lib-apache2-mod-wsgi. But it doesnt work. /indico/index.py return 404 Not Found :/

Comment: Read the docs: mod_python is not compatible with mod_wsgi. See: http://wsgi.org

Comment: Sorry, i mean, i removed mod_python then i installed mod_wsgi. And thanks for link. i will check up on this docs.